ScheduledJob scriptblock not resuming workflow job automatically
I have used the Powershell Register-ScheduledJob function to create a scheduled job with trigger and scriptblock referencing a new workflow saved as a new job with a restart in-between two tasks
however these will not trigger automatically as written in the script - only manually through command line
workflow testFlow {
  Set-Content -Path C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\Test.txt "Fail"
  Restart-Computer
  Start Sleep 10 #I put this in to stop the workflow from performing the second task while the restart was ongoing
  Set-Content -Path C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\Test.txt "Success"
}

$options = NewScheduledJobOption -RunElevated
$trig = new-jobTrigger -AtStartup #also tried -atlogin same behaviour observed
$block = {import-module PSworkflow; Resume-Job -Name newTestFlow}
Register-ScheduledJob -Name Resume -Trigger $trig -Scriptblock $block -ScheduledJobOption $options

testFlow -AsJob -JobName newTestFlow

After the Register-Scheduledjob command the scheduled job object is returned and printed to console. It can also be viewed at any point using get-scheduledjob and it is confirmed as Enabled and shows the scriptblock under "command". The trigger can also be viewed at any point using get-jobtrigger and shows that it is enabled
The job testFlow itself also can be viewed at any point using get-job where its state is shown as Suspended
I can manually run the scheduled job using the (get-scheduledjob -Name Resume).StartJob() command
and this produces output that shows that the scheduled job is running however get-job still shows that the newTestFlow workflow job is suspended
I don't understand what is going wrong here because I can copy and paste the contents of the scriptblock into command line and run them and the scheduled workflow job does run and the contents of test.txt are overwritten
afaik starting the scheduled job should run the contents of the scriptblock so what is the difference in what I'm observing?
Thanks
